# What is SS_SIMMODE_EXTERNAL in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, mex

I have seen [this documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/ssgetsimmode.html) but I really couldn't be sure what exactly is "external mode".(SS_SIMMODE_EXTERNAL)

Why am I worried?

I have a simulink model that contains a sfunction. Inside This sfunction there is a mexCallMatlab command. So, this will only work if the model is running under matlab environment.

Otherwise, if running in a compiled mode, this command will not work.

That leads us back to the original question: does "external mode" differentiates whether the model is running under matlab environment or compiled mode?

Comment: It is explained [in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtwin/ug/simulink-external-mode.html)

Comment: @Daniel, so it has nothing to do with compiled/not compiled.   Please answer this question to earn the points! :-)

Comment: It has nothing to do with compiled/not compiled.  As per @Daniel's link (and particularly the picture in the link), it is the name for using the Simulink front end as a way of looking at code running in real-time; changing parameters in that code, and viewing signal data being uploaded from that code.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Is there a way of knowing whether a simulink code is running RTW mode or not?

Comment: Across the top of the model's UI there is a selection box that shows the mode of the simulation. By default it says 'normal'.  If using External Mode it'll say 'external'.  From the Command Line this is accessed using `get_param(gcs,'SimulationMode')`.

Comment: What I meant is:  during runtime, inside a CMex SFunction, is it possible to implement a if/else condition to figure out if the sfunction has been compiled using Simulink RTW and it is running outside matlab environment? Something like:  if(ssIsCompiled == SS_IS_COMPILED) {}  obs: get_param is not a supported for command for RTW.

Comment: There is a symbol called MATLAB_MEX_FILE that is used to determine if the code is being compiled for real time or for simulation.  You'll see examples of using it in several places in your S-Function (assuming you started with the S-Function template).  It's straight forward to use, but for a little more info look at the doc by selecting the first link returned by `docsearch('S-Function Guidelines')`.

Comment: my god... you are the king of matlab :-)